# Development server-url not working inside expo-go app. (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Please provide the following:

```
SDK Version: 49.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android + IOS
```

When building my app all goes well until the project url get’s generated:

exp+doapp-432hz://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.101.17%3A8081

This Url isn’t clickable inside the expo app, both on android and iOS…

Steps to reproduce:
-Have an old expo-managed-app created with expo-cli 44.0.0
-Create a new project with create-expo-app (version 49.0.0)
Copy only javascript-files from the old app into the newly created app (omitting node_modules)
Running npm install to create node_modules folder
-Run npx expo start to create a new development server..

I’m kind of stuck on this one and I hope someone can help!
Here’s my app.json file:

```
`{
  "name": "solfeggio_music_player",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^7.0.3",
    "expo": "~49.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "^0.8.6",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-haste-map": "^29.7.0",
    "jotai": "^1.6.6",
    "metro-core": "^0.79.1",
    "nice-try": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "recyclerlistview": "^3.0.5",
    "walker": "^1.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}`
```

What I’ve tried:
-npm install -g expo-cli --force (to update the expo cli)
-disabling ‘display over other apps’ inside my android phone settings, however this setting is not supported on my phone…